# How to correct an "Undefined aggregationValue"

Tags: angular-ui, ui-grid

I am trying to get the sum of a column of integers in my grid.  How come the aggregationValue is `undefined` when in the `gridOptions` I have it set as

```
{ field: 'premium', name: 'Premium', width: '*', aggregationType: uiGridConstants.aggregationTypes.sum, aggregationHideLabel: true, cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents">${{COL_FIELD}}</div>' },
```

Here is a snapshot of the object. As you can see `aggregationType` is 2 (sum).
[image: aggregationvalue]

Here is a snap[shot of `uiGridConstants` that shows that it knows the `type` is `sum`
[image]

Here is an example of the object that makes up the grid

```
[
    {
        "id": "",
        "name": "Hadassah Potts",
        "type": "Wealth",
        "status": "Completed",
        "premium": 38823,
        "commission": 2039,
        "created_by": "Rose Strong",
        "last_updated": 75
    },
    {
        "id": "",
        "name": "Michael D. Hodge",
        "type": "Wealth",
        "status": "In Review",
        "premium": 37173,
        "commission": 4644,
        "created_by": "Thaddeus S. Wyatt",
        "last_updated": 49
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though im not using `showColumnFooter: true,` i needed to have it in the code...

Comment: This extra line of code completed the issue, and solved the problem directly